# Modelling free fall with Euler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to model free fall with air resistance using Euler method. I am using python and I was wondering if this is correct.

$v_k = v_{k-1}-(g+ \frac{k}{m}v_y^2) \Delta t$

$x_k = x_{k-1}+v_{k-1} \Delta t$

or in python code:

```
v +=(-g-k/m*pow(v,2))*dt
x += v*dt
```

Is this correct because my plots don't seem to differ, if anything the air resistance position results are lower compared to the position results without the air resistance?

Comment: Try switching the two lines of code. If you add $x$ by $v\Delta t$ after you increment $v$, then you're using the equation $x_k=x_{k-1}+v_k\Delta t$ which is different from the equation you wrote above.

Comment: @NobleMushtak This would yield more accurate results, but it won't be Euler's method. The _OP_ has to decide.

Comment: @ja72: Au contraire. Since $\dot v$ does not depend on $x$, this change produces the usual Euler method. It is not very useful to compare two order 1 methods for their marginal differences in an overall large error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code implements the symplectic Euler method. This is not that big a difference, the order of the method is still $1$.

Note that friction is always opposite to the direction of motion, in general it should be 
$$
\dot v = -g - \frac km\|v\|·v
$$
here in the case of vertical downwards motion this reduces, since $v<0$, to
$$
\dot v = -g +\frac km v^2
$$
Thus you need to change a sign in your formulas.